# Minecraft has weird graphical glitches

Tags: graphics, intel-graphics, minecraft

I am using Ubuntu 15.04 on a old Dell Inspiron 640m with up to date Intel HD graphics and Mesa/open GL. I don't have around 30 FPS with optimised settings and I'm using optifine. Strange forms appear when I use Minecraft

[image: large triangles in Minecraft window]

[image: Minecraft window]

Comment: Where did you install Java from?

Comment: official source

Comment: via command terminal

Comment: What command did you run?

Comment: i don't remember

Comment: it wasn't open jdk i'm sure

Comment: Well that's the only version available "from the terminal," unless you used `wget`. See if you can find what you installed.

Comment: okay moment please

Comment: these where the commands

Comment: 1  sudo apt-get install oracle-java8  <br/>
    2  sudo apt-get update  <br/>
    3  java -version  <br/>
    4  sudo apt-get install default-jre   <br/>
    5  sudo apt-add-repository ppa:webupd8team/java  <br/>
    6  sudo apt-get update <br/>
    7  sudo apt-get install oracle-java8-installer  <br/>

Comment: ignore the <br/> and the number before every command

Comment: can anyone help?

Comment: `sudo apt-get remove oracle-java8 oracle-java8-installer` then `sudo apt-get install openjdk-7-jdk`

Comment: why should openjdk solve the problem its even worse because i tried it once and it didn't even start minecraft

Comment: It's always worked for me, and I think it's under heavier development.

Comment: Thats a good argument. Ill try open jdk and tell you what it did

Comment: I'll post it as an answer.

Answer (score 0):

Run `sudo apt-get remove oracle-java8 oracle-java8-installer` and then `sudo apt-get install openjdk-7-jdk`. This will remove Oracle's Java and install OpenJDK, which is a little more stable and, I believe, is under more development.